# Result for passing empty string to indexOf() and lastIndexOf() for string containing text

Tags: javascript, string

I don't understand this behavior of `indexOf()` and `lastIndexOf()`:

```js
let foo = 'A';
foo.indexOf(''); // 0
foo.lastIndexOf(''); // 1
```

Based on the `indexOf()` result, I'd guess that an empty string is on either side of the character 'A' - but if that were the case, `lastIndexOf()` would return 2 instead of 1. What's going on here?

Comment: The empty string "appears" at the beginning and end of the string; it's *empty*, so it exists between every character.

Comment: likewise with the dupe - its formalized

Comment: @Pointy That's what I thought at first, but then wouldn't you get 2 as the ('A').lastIndexOf(''), with the empty string before and after 'A'?

Comment: Well there is no index 2 in "A"

Comment: There's no index 1 in 'A' either but the empty string is found at index 1. I don't know why it's not ([''][A]['']) with index 2 being the last empty string

Comment: The specification of `.lastIndexOf()` specifically says that if there's no starting position passed in as an argument, and the search string is the empty string, then the result is the length of the string. The length of "A" is 1.

Comment: I think you're referring to this part in the spec: "If position [called fromIndex on MDN] is undefined, the length of the String value is assumed, so as to search all of the String."
On the MDN page for lastIndexOf it has "If searchValue is an empty string, then fromIndex is returned." But it has "The default value is +Infinity" as the default for position/fromIndex. Maybe MDN should be edited to clarify.

Comment: I submitted a pull request to clarify this on the MDN page: https://github.com/mdn/content/pull/10662